# Semantic UI browser compatibility

Tags: browser, semantic-ui

I have seen here: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/blob/master/README.md the compatibility list ok this UI but I cannot understand which Firefox and Chrome version are last 2 version.

Where can I find the version number of these 2 browsers to have a sure list of compatibility?

**Thanks**
FA